# Demora en mostrar data - SQL SERVER 10MM registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar tengo una tabla que tiene 10MM de registros en SQL Server, al hacer select * from con join que esta abajo en la pregunta demora un montón y esa data es para mostrar en web pero demora demasiado,
he buscado que se puede aplicar indices he creado algunos.
pero igual al hacer select*from con join where demora mucho

```
SELECT  a.*,b.RDESTER,b.RDESADM
    FROM storage.[com_act].WBCH001 A  --select  * from  storage.[com_act].WBCH001
    left join storage.[ref].WJERCOR01 B ON A.HCODSEC=B.RCODSEC and B.RFECPRO=@fec
    where  case when @tip_cod=15 then  ISNULL(cast(B.RCODTER as nvarchar(10)),'9999') 
                when @tip_cod=14 then cast(B.RCODCOR as nvarchar(10)) 
                when @tip_cod=13 then B.RCODGRU
                when @tip_cod=11 then B.RCODADM else '1' end=IIF(@tip_cod=7,'1',@cod_rel)
    and case when @prod='TODO' then '1' else A.RDESPROD end =case when @prod='TODO' then '1' else @prod end  
    AND CASE WHEN @subpro='TODO' THEN '1' else a.HDTIPOPE  end=case when @subpro='TODO' then '1' else @subpro end
    AND CASE WHEN @madu='TODO' THEN '1' else cast(a.HCOSECHA as varchar(50))  end=case when @madu='TODO' then '1' else @madu end
```

create clustered index IDX_HNUMDOC
ON [com_act].WBCH001 (HNUMDOC)

create nonclustered index IDX_HCOSECHA
ON [com_act].WBCH001 (HCOSECHA)

create nonclustered index IDX_RDESPROD
ON [com_act].WBCH001 (RDESPROD)

create nonclustered index IDX_HDTIPOPE
ON [com_act].WBCH001 (HDTIPOPE)

create nonclustered index IDX_HCOSECHA
ON [com_act].WBCH001 (HCOSECHA)

create nonclustered index IDX_RCODTER
ON [com_act].WBCH001 (RCODTER)

create nonclustered index IDX_RCODCOR
ON [com_act].WBCH001 (RCODCOR)

create nonclustered index IDX_RCODGRU
ON [com_act].WBCH001 (RCODGRU)

create nonclustered index IDX_RCODADM
ON [com_act].WBCH001 (RCODADM)

create nonclustered index IDX_HDCODSEC
ON [com_act].WBCH001 (HDCODSEC)

Comment: puedes poner todos los índices que quieras, pero si estás haciendo un `SELECT *` sin `WHERE` (no mencionas nada de filtros) estás trayendo la tabla completa, nada lo va a apurar

Comment: @Lamak Muchas Gracias por comentar justo me dijeron lo mismo así que realice los filtro y otra tabla que me dijeron que le haga join, actualizare mi pregunta para que lo veas como lo estoy haciendo

Comment: Me atrevo a especular que tener muchos indices que incluyen una sola columna no creo que sirva de mucho para la consulta. Si la tabla `WBCH001` es la que tiene 10MM de registros, con el `LEFT JOIN` la estás leyendo completa. Mi recomendación para este tipo de casos es analizar el [plan de ejecución](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sqlallproducts-allversions). Verifica también si puedes escribir esa consulta sin tanto ´case´ de acuerdo con mi experiencia hace las consultas más lentas

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez si entiendo, o habra alguna otra manera ?

Comment: Seguramente hay otra forma de hacerlo, pero en mi opinon falta mucho detalle que ayude a entender el conjunto de datos, una mejor descripción de las tablas y columnas porque de sus nombres solo se pueden hacer especulaciones. Cuál es el objetivo de cada `case` en la consulta, cuál de las tablas es la que tiene 10MM de registros, etc.